# javascript compare current time to variable every minute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, setinterval

I have a start date defined in a database and I need to know when the start date is greater then the current time. I've tried using setInterval, but I can't access the updated time outside the setInterval function.

This is what I need to compare the current time to the database variable:

```
if(startDate > now) {
 var status = 'pre';
}
```

I've tried using setInterval as follows, but I can't access the updated (current time) outside of the setInterval function.

```
setInterval(function(){
  now = moment(new Date()).format();
  console.log('time1 ', now); // this works
}, 1000);

console.log('time2 ', now); // this doesn't
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The scope is wrong, you should define "now" outside of setInterval.

Comment: define global variable to get value outside

Comment: Could you show the component in which this is used?

Comment: I'm having no luck with this - does anyone have an example to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using react-interval https://github.com/nkbt/react-interval to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 var now = new Date();
 setInterval(function(){
    now = new Date();
 console.log('time1 ',   now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes()+":"+now.getSeconds()); 
}, 1000);

 console.log('time2 ',   now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes()+":"+now.getSeconds()); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks - but I just got the same results - only time1 was updated each second